# Mithril.js - getScript

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'm trying add component `Eshop_pane`" to some div. Component `Eshop_panel` is in another external script, so I add this part of script with `$.getScript`, but this component won't show up. Can you help me?

```
m("div.fr", [
    m("div", {class: ctrl.uid}),
    $.getScript("some_panel.js").done(function(script) {
       m.component(Eshop_panel, {})
    })
])

//some_panel.js
var Eshop_panel = {
    view: function() {
        return [
            m("div", "Hello world!"),
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: `$.getScript` is a jQuery method...not a Mithril function. Have you included jQuery? What does the console tell you?

Comment: Instead of loading the `Eshop_panel` component via the `getScript` function, you should require it as a module using a tool like browserify. If you want to load the external file the way you are already doing it, though, you should place the `getScript` call on the controller (it's better on the model, if you have one), and then call `m.redraw` on the `done` callback, making the `Eshop_panel` component available on the view (`ctrl.panel_component`, for example) with a getter/setter that should be initialised to `null` while the script is loading.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to load the script before any of the relevant code is actually executed, eg:

```
$.getScript("some_panel.js").done(function(script) {
  m.mount(someElem, { // Ie, don't actually do the mount until everything's ready
    view: function() {
      return m("div.fr", [
        m("div", {class: ctrl.uid}),
         m.component(window.Eshop_panel, {})
        })
      ])
    }
  })
})
```

Or another option could be to display a placeholder until the script has loaded:

```
$.getScript("some_panel.js").done(function(script) {
  m.redraw()    
})
...
m("div.fr", [
    m("div", {class: ctrl.uid}),
    typeof window.Eshop_panel === 'undefined' ? 'Loading...' : m.component(Eshop_panel, {})
])
```

(I'd suggest considering investigating tools like AMD or Browserify (etc) to help with this type of scenario. i.e. I wouldn't do it this way personally, but it might be the simplest option for what you're trying to achieve.)